# Doubling the size of a closet with two rods

Tags: mounting, studs, closet

The closet currently contains one 48" rod, two flanges and two 1" wooden piece to support a shelf.

[image]

I'm thinking of moving this one higher and installing a second rod lower to double the space in the high-ceiling closet, but as a home-improvement beginner I have a few questions:

1. Are these wooden pieces always needed? The walls are 50" apart and standard rods I found were 48" long, so I can guess the landlord either had to complement with the wooden pieces or used them to support the shelf. In my previous, the flangers were nailed straight into the wall, but in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LimIOo_cuTA) the guy is moving the wood higher as well.
2. One side is a drywall, I'm not sure it's ideal to support a rod and the heavy clothes, let alone two rods. Is it safe?
3. If I need to install the wooden pieces, where can I find some in NYC?
4. How should I look for studs, and what kind of nails are recommended?

Comment: I use fence pipes from the fence store or at home depot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocks of wood your refering to serve two purposes, a resting place for the shelf above them and to provide a sturdy place for you to screw in the holders for the closet rod.

I understand once you move your rod up and install another one lower you probably won't use a shelf but I still recommend using the blocks of wood. Sure you could screw directly into the drywall, and maybe even hit a stud, but the chance that your closet rod will fall is much less if you use this block of wood.

If you have a hard time getting to a home improvement store to get wood, you can probably even use a board taken from a wooden pallet for this purpose. Just cut it to size, paint it up and it'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks! I finally did it: went to Home Depot, sawed pieces of wood and two rods to the right dimensions, installed everything using drywall screws, put the shelf back, and replaced the door with curtains: [see the result](http://screenshots.kevinbongart.net/QCtu.jpg)